# Java Label Timer and Saving

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe

Let me explain what I am trying to do.

I have two classes extending `JFrame`, the `StartJFrame` and `TestingJFrame`. In the main method, I start up a `StartJFrame`. It has a single button, start. When that is pressed, I have it set up to hide that frame and start up the `TestingJFrame`. Right now I don't have anything in the T`estingJFrame`.

In that screen, I want to have a label in the bottom right corner that is a timer, starting on 45 seconds and counting down to 0. I also need to have some code run every 10th of a second, and collect some data. There will be two buttons in the `TestingJFrame`, Yes and No. When one of them is pressed, it should stop the timer and save the information.

The data is basically just doubles. I am only going to be collecting data once per run of the program. I have a `UserData` class that holds some information about the test subject, and a list of doubles, it is added to every 10th of a second. I have a general idea how to save the data in java.

My question is, how should I set up the timer, so that it will count down from 45 seconds, and when it reaches 0 or the user presses the yes or no button it will call a function to save the data? I think I can handle the saving data part.

Sorry if this is really easy, I'm new to Java (from c#) and Swing has been confusing me a bit.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part (show the count down and stopping the timer) is relatively easy...

```
public class TimerTest01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimerTest01();
    }

    public TimerTest01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private Timer timer;
        private long startTime;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            label = new JLabel("...");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            final JButton btn = new JButton("Start");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (timer.isRunning()) {
                        timer.stop();
                        btn.setText("Start");
                    } else {
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        timer.restart();
                        btn.setText("Stop");
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            add(label);
            add(btn);

            timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    long endTime = (startTime + 45000);
                    long timeLeft = endTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (timeLeft < 0) {
                        timer.stop();
                        label.setText("Expired");
                        btn.setText("Start");
                    } else {
                        label.setText(Long.toString(timeLeft / 1000));
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more info

The second part of you question is to vague to reliably provide you with an answer.  Where is the data coming from?  How is collected??

Comment: Thanks! Nevermind the second question, all I really need to do is have the timer be updated every 10th of a second, and have a method to place code in. But what I don't understand is how to have the timer be every 10th a a second, but only have the label updated every second. If I have a variable to count the number of updates in the timer and use modulus to get every tenth one would that be suitable? Or is there a different way?

Comment: Just be aware that `SwingTimer` only guarantees that it will trigger a result at least every *n* milliseconds.  It is better to sync back to the system clock (which has it's own issues), but would be more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to setup your timer. You can have a look at [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) too.

Comment: Thanks! Although that wasn't my only question. How do I use the label to be put in the bottom right corner and be updated every second?

Comment: @user2018829 You use a layout manager that meets your needs.  Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).  Also, you use the timer to count backwards ;)

Comment: +1 for the Timer suggestion and the link to the tutorial. As a new Swing programmer I'm sure the poster will find all the section in the tutorial beneficial.